Leaflet Map with file download in popup, onclick event on anchor tag not working
I cant get this anchor to work for a download, and after clicking it, it should be showing a DIV.. What am I doing wrong?
Please see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gimoya/b75haye4/15/
var cities = new L.LayerGroup();

var M = L.marker([44, 11]);

var gpxLink = document.createElement('a');
gpxLink.download = 'TrailName' + '.gpx';
gpxLink.innerHTML = 'GPX-Download'; 

/* setting onClick here does nothing? */
gpxLink.onClick = function() {
    document.querySelector('.kofi_reminder').style.visibility = 'visible';
};

gpxLink.href = "foo.html";
      
var popupContent =
    '<p><div>Name</div></p>'
    + '<div class="pop_gpx_text"> ' +  gpxLink.outerHTML + ' </div>'
    + '<div class="kofi_reminder">'
        + '<div class="kofi_button" title="Unterstütze diese Seite!"><a href="https://ko-fi.com/C1C74GQ0I" target="_blank">'
        +   '<img id="kofi_img_div" class="kofi_img" src="https://tiroltrailhead.com/legacy_trails/images/kofi_s_logo_nolabel.png"/>'
        +   '<span style="margin-left:14px;">Click to Support!</span>'  
        + '</div></div>'
    
M.bindPopup(popupContent, {closeOnClick: true, className: 'trailPopupClass'});

M.addTo(cities);


var mtbmapAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
  '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
  'Tiles © <a href="http://mtbmap.cz">mtbmap</a>';
var mtbmapUrl = 'http://tile.mtbmap.cz/mtbmap_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var mtbmapLayer = L.tileLayer(mtbmapUrl, {
  attribution: mtbmapAttr
});

var baseLayers = {
  "OSM-MTBMap": mtbmapLayer
};

var overlays = {
  "Cities": cities
};

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [44, 11],
  zoom: 7,
  layers: [mtbmapLayer, cities]
});

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);


Same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77560267/leaflet-2nd-map-kills-first/77560625 - any event handlers attached to a DOM node go away once that node is serialized into a string.

ah, I see that the string var popupContent does not have the onclick event. But how then set this event handler properly? Thanks for your input @IvanSanchez!

Either avoid serializing to strings, or attach events once the string has been turned into DOM nodes in the document (i.e. the popup opens and its attached to the DOM, or you create a document fragment and work with that).
